# WebView.Navigated and ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

Is it possible for to capture the Navigated Event of WebView Control in Xamarin Form when using Prism in View Model ? My Control Definition looks like following

```
<WebView Source="{Binding GatewayPageSource,Mode=TwoWay}" WidthRequest="500" HeightRequest="500" />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The WebView is not particularly MVVM friendly as it has no built in commands. There are a couple of ways that you could tackle this though.

1) Extend WebView to a custom control that includes BindableProperties for Commands associated with the events you wish to work with. Similar to the following.

```
public class MvvmWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty NavigatingCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create( nameof( NavigatingCommand ), typeof( ICommand ), typeof( MvvmWebView ), null );

    public static readonly BindableProperty NavigatedCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create( nameof( NavigatedCommand ), typeof( ICommand ), typeof( MvvmWebView ), null );

    public MvvmWebView()
    {
        Navigating += ( s, e ) =>
        {
            if( NavigatingCommand?.CanExecute( e ) ?? false )
                NavigatingCommand.Execute( e );
        };

        Navigated += ( s, e ) => {
            if( NavigatedCommand?.CanExecute( e ) ?? false )
                NavigatedCommand.Execute( e );
        }
    }

    public ICommand NavigatingCommand
    {
        get { return ( ICommand )GetValue( NavigatingCommandProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( NavigatingCommandProperty, value ); }
    }

    public ICommand NavigatedCommand
    {
        get { return ( ICommand )GetValue( NavigatedCommandProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( NavigatedCommandProperty, value ); }
    }
}
```

2) You could add a behavior to the WebView similar to the blog post from [Xamarin](https://blog.xamarin.com/turn-events-into-commands-with-behaviors/) as already mentioned. It's also worth noting that Prism Forms 6.3.0-pre2 will come with the [EventToCommandBehavior](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Forms/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior.cs), and should be available soon.

Comment: Prism 6.3.0-pre2 is now available on NuGet, as mentioned you can use the EventToCommand behavior included in Prism.Forms to execute your commands for a specified event.

Comment: this is from 2 years ago.. use the EventToCommandBehavior built in to Prism. Also worth noting that the EventToCommandBehavior should be in [Xamarin.Forms 4.0](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/6047)

Answer (score 1):

WebView has event called Navigated, you can bind this event to your ViewModels command with [EventToCommandBehaviour](https://blog.xamarin.com/turn-events-into-commands-with-behaviors)

Comment: Hi Vitalii, Thanks for the reply. I tried it according to the link you had provided. The Command gets filled, however, when Command.Execute is executed in the Behavior class, I get an object not defined error. Could you help me out ?

Comment: Exact Error -  Ex {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at namespace.Behavior.WebViewNavigationBehavior.WebView_Navigated (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.WebNavigatedEventArgs e) [0x00024] in path\WebViewNavigationBehavior.cs:47 } System.NullReferenceException